# Looping an OnTime Event Crashes the Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Here's what I've put in my module:

```
Public Times As Boolean
```

---

```
Sub start()

Times = True

Track:
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Run"
If Times = True Then GoTo Track

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub run()

Range("E3").Value = Range("E3").Value + TimeValue("00:00:01")

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub Tend()

Times = False

End Sub
```

---

Now, when I run Start(), My Excel crashes.
Kindly Advice

Comment: Loops can be resource intensive. You can try adding a `DoEvents` somewhere in your loop to see if that prevents it from crashing.

Comment: That works.. thanks @K.Davis :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code in Start is a tight loop which is not what you want to do I think.

```
Public Times As Boolean

Sub start()
    Times = True
    Run    
End Sub

Sub run()
    If Not Times Then Exit Sub  
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "Run"
    Range("E3").Value = Range("E3").Value + TimeValue("00:00:01")
End Sub

Sub Tend() 
    Times = False
End Sub
```